# Is there a way to create column vectors in numpy without having to create a list of lists?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Say I want to multiply a matrix by a vector:

```
[1 2 3]   [10]
[4 5 6] * [11]
[7 8 9]   [12]
```

In Python using Numpy I would do it like this:

```
from numpy import *

A = matrix(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]])

B = matrix(
    [[10], [11], [12]])

print(A * B)
```

However as you can see, in order to define matrix B correctly, I have to type `[[10], [11], [12]]`, and that is a bit tedious. Is there something that just constructs a vector, so I could type something like `vector([10, 11, 12])` instead of `matrix([[10], [11], [12]])`?

Answer (score 4):

You can create B as a numpy array and then use the method `dot`

```
B=np.array([10,11,12])
print(A.dot(B)) #Use A.dot(B).T if you need to keep the original dimension
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just transpose the matrix:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.matrix(
   ...:     [[1, 2, 3],
   ...:      [4, 5, 6],
   ...:      [7, 8, 9]])
   ...:

In [3]: B = np.matrix([10, 11, 12]).T

In [4]: print(A * B)
[[ 68]
 [167]
 [266]]
```

Comment: a note to the OP: always use the matrix class with caution. it does not behave like an array at times when you think it would.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `c_` column assembly object:

```
>>> np.c_[[10,11,12]]
array([[10],
       [11],
       [12]])
```

or

```
>>> np.c_[10:13]
array([[10],
       [11],
       [12]])
```

or with `linspace` semantics

```
>>> np.c_[10:12:3j]
array([[10.],
       [11.],
       [12.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy option is to create a new axis of dimension None:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    ])

B = np.array([ 10, 11, 12 ])

print(A * B[:,None])
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different than the other answers, but here are my 2 cents :)

Python's zip might be of help here!

```
In [13]: blist = [10, 11, 12]

In [14]: B = matrix(zip(blist))

In [15]: print B
[[10]
 [11]
 [12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
B = np.array([10, 11, 12]).reshape(-1, 1)

>>> array([[10],
           [11],
           [12]])
```